# useState not calling as a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Our code as shown in "https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/project-ko-uXAYKo" is not calling the use state function when we have it to import from react.

we've tried to use state with importing it, not importing, and trying to import from react native and nothing has shown to work.

Comment: Hooks like `useState` are only available in function-based components, not in class based ones. If you want to use this hooks, convert your component to be a function. https://reactnative.dev/docs/intro-react#state

Comment: thank you lad, we'll switch it over!